# Why different ftp user ids?

Tags: azure-web-app-service

For my Azure Web Service, under Properties, the FTP/DEPLOYMENT USER seems to be of the form:

> websitename\azuresubscriptiondirectoryname

But under Deployment Center, FTP, Dashboard, it is of the form:

> websitename\$websitename

Where do I get the password for the first one, ie FTP/DEPLOYMENT USER?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one are user-level deployment credentials, they allow you to deploy any app in your account, as opposed to app-level credentials (the second you mentioned).

Assuming that you haven't configured them yet, you have to open the "Deployment center" section of your App Service. If you have multiple App Services, any of them will do).
Refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-configure-credentials#userscope) for a how-to.